# BIOS mem test hangs up with new DIMM installed

Tags: memory, bsod, ddr3

I've got MSI H55M-E33 motherboard with 2x2GB DIMM DDR3 Kingston KVR1333D3N9/2G modules which work fine for years in 1333 Dual channel mode. In accordance with the user manual, the motherboard supports DDR3 up to 1333 without any restrictions. It has 4 DIMM slots and supports up to 16GB RAM.

Recently I've decided to increase memory amount adding some 4GB modules.
I removed old modules and tried with 1xKingston KVR13N9S8/4 and then 2xKingmax DDR3 1333 DIMM 4Gb with the same result - BIOS recognizes new memory DIMM(s), but the motherboard hangs up on memory test run or (if I turn off the test) Windows 7 x64 dies with BSOD.

Old memory modules still work fine.

What can be the reason? Is something wrong with DIMMs or MB?

Comment: The first step.  Update the firmware to the current released revision and see if that solves it.

Comment: I've already updated BIOS to the latest version 1.10

Comment: What are the voltage requirements of modules you purchased?

Comment: The voltage is 1.5V

Comment: What voltages does the motherboard support?

Comment: The motherboard supports voltage values from 0.978V to 1.898V.
I'm using Auto (1.630V) BTW all my settings are set to Auto.

Comment: Don't use Auto if Auto sets the voltage to 1.630 V